# How to replace a whole line (between 2 words) using sed?

Tags: shell, awk, sed

Suppose I have text as:

```
This is a sample text.
I have 2 sentences.
text is present there.
```

I need to replace whole text between two 'text' words. The required solution should be

```
This is a sample text.
I have new sentences.
text is present there.
```

I tried using the below command but its not working:

```
sed -i 's/text.*?text/text\
\nI have new sentence/g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following. `sed` doesn't support lazy matching in regex. With `awk`'s RS you could do the substitution with your shown samples only. You need to create variable  `val` which has new value in it. Then in `awk` performing simple substitution operation will so the rest to get your expected output.

```
awk -v val="your_new_line_Value" -v RS="" '
{
  sub(/text\.\n*[^\n]*\n*text/,"text.\n"val"\ntext")
}
1
' Input_file
```

Above code will print output on terminal, once you are Happy with results of above and want to save output into Input_file itself then try following code.

```
awk -v val="your_new_line_Value" -v RS="" '
{
  sub(/text\.\n*[^\n]*\n*text/,"text.\n"val"\ntext")
}
1
' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

You have already solved your problem using `awk`, but in case anyone else will be looking for a `sed` solution in the future, here's a `sed` script that does what you needed. Granted, the script is using some advanced `sed` features, but that's the fun part of it :)

###### replace.sed

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sed -nEf

# This pattern determines the start marker for the range of lines where we
# want to perform the substitution. In our case the pattern is any line that
# ends with "text." — the `$` symbol meaning end-of-line.
/text\.$/ {
  # [p]rint the start-marker line.
  p

  # Next, we'll read lines (using `n`) in a loop, so mark this point in
  # the script as the beginning of the loop using a label called `loop`.
  :loop

  # Read the next line.
  n

  # If the last read line doesn't match the pattern for the end marker,
  # just continue looping by [b]ranching to the `:loop` label.
  /^text/! {
    b loop
  }

  # If the last read line matches the end marker pattern, then just insert
  # the text we want and print the last read line. The net effect is that
  # all the previous read lines will be replaced by the inserted text.
  /^text/ {
    # Insert the replacement text
    i\
I have a new sentence.

    # [print] the end-marker line
    p
  }

  # Exit the script, so that we don't hit the [p]rint command below.
  b
}

# Print all other lines.
p
```

#### Usage

```sh
$ cat lines.txt
foo
This is a sample text.
I have many sentences.
I have many sentences.
I have many sentences.
I have many sentences.
text is present there.
bar
$
$ ./replace.sed lines.txt
foo
This is a sample text.
I have a new sentence.
text is present there.
bar
```

Comment: An elegant solution however it should be noted that if there were other lines above or below those containing the delimiting words, they too would not be printed. It is not clear from the OP if this is intended but if it were, then the original file could just be replaced by one with the three line solution.

Comment: @potong yes, you're right. I missed handling that case, which was probably needed in the OP's problem. One more reason to love code reviews :)

Comment: If you love code reviews may I offer some more? First, the `.` matches any single character so I think you intended `\.`. Second, `{...}` group commands but are unnecessary for a single command ,so `/^text/! b loop` would be suffice. Third, since that single command is flow control, it infers anything following does match and so another match is not necessary. Finally, since the `-n` option is invoked, a `p` command or flag is needed to print lines and should be placed outside of the chain of commands that constitute the solution as a catch all. HTH

Comment: @potong thanks! It's helpful, indeed. For 1) yes, you're right, I somehow always get tripped up by that even though I know it's a special character in REs; 2). Using braces was just a stylistic choice here — I feel that they convey better the belonging of a command to a pattern; 3) You are quite right, the end-marker match could have been omitted; 4) I agree, I've actually amended the answer probably a few seconds before you posted your comment. Thanks again for the review!

Answer (score 1):

Substitue

`sed -i 's/I have 2 sentences./I have new sentences./g'`

`sed -i 's/[A-Z]\s[a-z].*/I have new sentences./g'`

Insert

`sed -i -e '2iI have new sentences.' -e '2d'`

Comment: What if I don't know how many sentences are there between 'text' and 'text'?Then how does your substitue work?

Comment: @saiakhil If you do not know what you are substituting, then it is not possible to substitute. You will need a pattern to subtitute against. You may need additional operators such as labels to branch and `N; n;` for new line substitutions.  https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Answer (score 1):

`I need to replace whole text between two 'text' words.`

If I understand, first `text.` (with a dot) is at the end of first line and second `text` at the beginning of third line.  With `awk` you can get `the required solution` adding values to var `s`:

```
awk -v s='\nI have new sentences.\n' '/text.?$/ {s=$0 s;next} /^text/ {s=s $0;print s;s=""}' file
This is a sample text.
I have new sentences.
text is present there.
```